# Polymer website takes 5 seconds to load

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

My little Polymer 1.0 Starter Kit app takes 5 seconds to load. The site also uses [Page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/).

I am following [this tutorial](https://aerotwist.com/blog/polymer-for-the-performance-obsessed/) on how to speed up your polymer app. But I'm on the video section.

I've used [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) in my app and the set up:

```
<head>
 <script src="scripts/loadCSS.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/onloadCSS.js"></script>

 <!-- build:js bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js -->
 <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
 <!-- endbuild -->

 <!-- will be replaced with elements/elements.vulcanized.html -->
 <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
 <!-- endreplace-->
</head>

<body>
 <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
 <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <paper-header-panel main mode="waterfall">
   <paper-toolbar>
    //web links etc
   </paper-toolbar>
   // Main Content
   <div class="content" style="display:none">
    <script>
     onloadCSS(loadCSS('styles/main.css'), function() {
      document.querySelector('.content')
       .style.display = ''; // should show the content after css is loaded?
     });
    </script>
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css"></noscript>
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/skeleton.css"></noscript>
    <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
     // all the elements ie: <my-app></my-app>
    </iron-papes>
   </div>
  </paper-header-panel>
 </template>
</body>
```

Only the `<paper-toolbar>` loads and nothing else. Why `.style.display = '';` does not work?

Thanks

Comment: does it load faster without page.js??

Comment: I have to use that js

Comment: you need to test without, to make sure is not that causing the issue